# Deleting empty index column pandas dataframe - labels [' '] not contained in axis

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

The column **numeroLote** is between a range of `5` to `25` values.
I want to create an export `csv` file to each data when **numeroLote** change their value and I perform the following:

```
for i in range(5,26):
    print(i)
    a = racimitos[racimitos['numeroLote']==i][['peso','fecha','numeroLote']]
    a.to_csv('racimitos{}.csv'.format(i), sep=',', header=True, index=True)
```

And then, I get datasets similar to:

[image]

An additional column is generated like the one enclosed in the red box above …

I try to remove this column of the following way:

```
for i in range(5,26):
    print(i)
    a = racimitos[racimitos['numeroLote']==i][['peso','fecha','numeroLote']]
    a.to_csv('racimitos{}.csv'.format(i), sep=',', header=True, index=True)
    a.drop(columns=[' '], axis=1,)
```

But I get this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-e3ad718d5396> in <module>()
      9     a = racimitos[racimitos['numeroLote']==i][['peso','fecha','numeroLote']]
     10     a.to_csv('racimitos{}.csv'.format(i), sep=',', header=True, index=True)
---> 11     a.drop(columns=[' '], axis=1,)

~/anaconda3/envs/sioma/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   4385             if errors != 'ignore':
   4386                 raise KeyError(
-> 4387                     'labels %s not contained in axis' % labels[mask])
   4388             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   4389         return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: "labels [' '] not contained in axis"
```

How to can I remove this empty column index which is generated when I execute the export `to.csv` ?

Comment: You want `index=False`. Also curious why you are keeping the `numeroLote` column when it's clear what it's value is from the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instead want `index=False`, like so:

```
for i in range(5,26):
    a = racimitos[racimitos['numeroLote']==i][['peso','fecha','numeroLote']]
    a.to_csv('racimitos{}.csv'.format(i), sep=',', header=True, index=False)
```

As an aside, I don't think it's necessary to include the `numeroLote` column when printing to the .csv file, simply because you capture it's value in the filename.

Here is a much more efficient solution IMO using `groupby()`:

```
grouped = racimitos.groupby('numeroLote')[['peso','fecha']]
[grouped.get_group(key).to_csv('racimitos{}.csv'.format(key), index=False) for key, item in grouped]
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to drop that unnamed column, you could select all columns starting from index 1.

```
a = a.iloc[:, 1:]
```

Comment: Reason for my downvote - This solution is really avoiding the root of the problem, which is writing the index to the output dataframe in the first place.

Comment: If you really want to delete that one... you could use similar approach to delete by index. i.e...a.drop(a.columns[[0]], axis=1)